# Looking to bring runtime under 20 seconds

Tags: python, optimization, runtime

The following program, balanced_centrifuge(), takes positive integers (n, k), where k <= n, and determines whether k and n-k can be expressed as a sum of the prime factors of n (note, repetition of factors is allowed). I've been able to walk through the logic of this code and it makes sense, but the runtime is over 20 seconds which is too slow for my tester. It works for all the suggested test cases however, (6,3), (7,0), (15,8), (222, 107), and (1234, 43). Where is the slowdown occurring?

```
import itertools
def balanced_centrifuge(n,k):
  if n == 1:
    return False
  if k == 0 or n - k == 0:
    return True
  primes = get_primes(n)
  final_answer =  is_sum(primes, k) and is_sum(primes,n-k)
  return final_answer
  
def get_primes(n):
  i = 2
  factors = []
  while i * i <= n:
    if n % i != 0:
        i += 1
    else:
        n //= i
        factors.append(i)
  if n > 1:
    factors.append(n)
  return factors

def is_sum(primes, goal):
  if primes == []:
    return False
  for i in range(goal//primes[0]+1, 0, -1):
    ans = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(primes, i)
    for comb in ans:
        #print(comb)
          # single tuple with i elements to try
        if sum(comb) == goal:
            return True
  return False
```

Comment: Your implementation may or may not be correct but I've tried this with all of the n,k values shown in your question and the program runs in under 1 second

Comment: My thinking is that the number of tuples I need to consider can be optimized... namely the loop in the is_sum program.

Comment: Duplicate values of `comb` are possible. Try memoizing the summation. Look for short-circuit opportunities in the `for-loop`.  Instead of memoizing the summation, just detect duplicate `comb` values and skip the iteration. If you can generate `comb`S in order of increasing `sum(comb)` then you can short-circuit the outer loop once `sum(comb) > goal`.
Like @LancelotduLac, the code ran in less than one second in my environment.